# Split a text file according to data into multiple files in Unix

Tags: unix, split

Assume the input file is sorted according to column 3 (the barcode begins with "TCGA"):

```
Joe 1 TCGA-A8-A08L-01A-11W-A019-09 T
John 2 TCGA-A8-A08L-01A-11W-A019-09 T
Jack 3 TCGA-A8-CVDL-01A-11W-A019-09 T
Jane 4 TCGA-A8-CVDL-01A-11W-A019-09 F
Justin 5 TCGA-A8-E08L-01A-11W-A019-09 F
Jasmine 6 TCGA-A8-E08L-01A-11W-A019-09 T
Jacob 7 TCGA-A8-E08L-01A-11W-A019-09 T
```

I want to split this text into new files with respect to 3rd column content as (just output 1st column values):

File-1:

```
Joe
John
```

File-2:

```
Jack
Jane
```

File-3:

```
Justin
Jasmine
Jacob
```

How can I achieve this?

Edit: The name of the files can be anything. It is not problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried many things such as using split, adding prefix and suffix for each segment, keeping track of previous line, etc. but there is an extremely simple solution that I could not think of at first:

```
awk -F' ' '{print $1 > $3}' inputfile
```

The name of files will be column 3's content.

Comment: your answer doesn't line up with  your question (IMHO), but glad you got what you need. Be sure to accept your answer after 48 hrs (I think) so others won't be looking to solve this problem. Good luck.

Comment: In fact, I do not care name of the file in this situation and except this detail, it works well. As you know, the content of column 3 will be the name of created files and so the contents of column 1 will be separated considering uniqueness of column 3. I did not want to restrict the name of files. I should mention it, you are right. Thanks.